# Keeping track of accessibility between parameters and methods

Tags: c#

I've read through [THIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) and [THIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx).

I'm finding it hard to keep track of accessibility in this code.

This is the error:

> Error 1   Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'LifeWorxWS.QLINKInstructionDetail.InstructionType' is less accessible than method 'LifeWorxWS.QLINKInstructionDetail.QLINK_Submit_Instruction(LifeWorxWS.QLINKInstructionDetail.InstructionType, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, double, string, string)'   C:\Projects\Sub version workspaces\N2A\LifeWorxWS\LifeWorxWS\QLINK\QLINKInterfaces.cs   163 35  LifeWorxWS

In QLINKINterfaces.cs this is the code:

```
    public class QLINKInstructionDetail
{
    #region "Submit Instructions"
    public QLINKInstruction QLINK_Submit_New_Instruction(string pstrSalaryMonth, string pstrPayrollCode, string pstrEmployeeNr, string pstrSurname, string pstrInitials, string pstrRSAIDNr, string pstrReferenceNr, double pdblAmount, string pstrStartDate)
    {
        try
        {
            //Call SubmitInstruction
            QLINKInstruction lobjQLINKInstructionDC = new QLINKInstruction();
            lobjQLINKInstructionDC = QLINK_Submit_Instruction(InstructionType.QADD, pstrSalaryMonth, pstrPayrollCode, pstrEmployeeNr, pstrSurname, pstrInitials, pstrRSAIDNr, pstrReferenceNr, pdblAmount, pstrStartDate, "");

            //return datacontract as populated return values
            return lobjQLINKInstructionDC;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { return ""; }

    }
    internal QLINKInstruction QLINK_Submit_Instruction(InstructionType penmInstructionType, string pstrSalaryMonth, string pstrPayrollCode, string pstrEmployeeNr, string pstrSurname, string pstrInitials, string pstrRSAIDNr, string pstrReferenceNr, double pdblAmount, string pstrStartDate, string pstrEndDate)
    {
        try
        {
            //Get Header
            string lstrHeader = GetHeader();

            //Get Detail
            string lstrDetail = GetDetailTransaction();

            string lstrCombinedXMLInstruction = "";

            lstrCombinedXMLInstruction = "<QLINK>" + Environment.NewLine;
            lstrCombinedXMLInstruction += lstrHeader + Environment.NewLine;
            lstrCombinedXMLInstruction += lstrDetail + Environment.NewLine;
            lstrCombinedXMLInstruction += "</QLINK>" + Environment.NewLine;

            //Submit packet - page 15 to QLINK and get/handle response


            //set return values
            QLINKInstruction lobjQLINKInstructionDC = new QLINKInstruction();

            //return datacontract as populated return values
            return lobjQLINKInstructionDC;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { return ""; }

    }

    #endregion "Submit Instructions"

    #region "Enums"
    private enum InstructionType
    {
        QADD = 1,
        QUPD = 2,
        QDEL = 3
    }

    #endregion "Enums"

}
```

The way I understand it there should not be a problem because `QLINKInstructionDetail`can be accessed by any other code in the same assembly,  `QLINK_Submit_Instruction`can be accessed by any code in the same assembly and `InstructionType`  can be accessed only by code in the same class and it is in the `QLINKInstructionDetail` where `QLINK_Submit_Instruction` is also situated.

Is is obviously not the correct understanding (otherwise the error would not show up). 
Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong in this code,please?

Comment: Your question is terribly unclear. Please provide a short, yet complete reproduce of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`InstructionType` is delared as `private`, you have to declare it as `internal` or `public`. The type has to be used of the calling method, because it is used as a parameter of the method `QLINK_Submit_Instruction`.

Otherwise you have to delcare the method as private.